# Add migration for existing database

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-2.1

I have database with data. I have context.
Now I am trying to add intial migration for existing DB.

I tried the following command in PM Console:

```
add-migration InitialCreate -IgnoreChanges
```

But as I understood, `-IgnoreChanges` doesn't work for EF Core.

Is there way to solve this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2167

Answer (score 0):

In result I've applied workaround solution for this issue.

1. In MSSQL Management Studio the script to insert data was generated.(I put it into text file not to lose it).
2. I removed database.
3. In Package Manager Console of Visual Studio I triggered command `Add-Migration InitialExist` for data-layer project. Outcome of this action is appearing `Migrations` folder with first migration and context snapshot.
4. Then the command `Update-database` was executed In Package Manager Console. It created new database with `__EFMigrationsHistory` table. This table contains important initial record. Script to create this table is following:

```sql
    USE [my_database_name]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory]    Script Date: 6/19/2019 3:16:26 PM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__EFMigrationsHistory](
        [MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
        [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [MigrationId] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

5. In MSSQL Management Studio I applied previously generated script to insert my data.

Done. These actions allowed me to initialize migration stuff on my dev machine.
For production I run the script creating table `__EFMigrationsHistory` and inserting initial record against prod database.